# Non-integer values in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Is there a way to store and compute non-integer values in verilog, (say x = 5/2 = 2.5 ).
Can I compute and store 2.5 in x defined above?

Comment: You can juggle bits as you like, and there are many ways to encode non-integer numbers. But I suppose you're asking for something built into Verilog?

Comment: yes, like do we have any keyword or function using which we can store non-integer values also into the registers (eg, signed implies we are storing signed numbers into the registers).

Comment: There are `real` data types in the SystemVerilog language for modeling, but if you are asking about a built-in type that can be synthesized into hardware, that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `real registers` to store real values, i.e.:

```
real float; // a register to store real value
```

Usually it's a 64-bit wide data type that stores floating-point values. But not all Verilog operators can be used with expression involving real numbers and real registers. Concatenations, modulus operator, case equality, bit-wise operators, reduction operators shift operators, bit-selects and part-selects on real type variables are not allowed.

Simple example:

```
module ecample;
real r;

initial begin 
  r = 123456e-3;
  $display("r=%f",r); // r = 123.456000
  #20 r = r / 2;
  $display("r=%f",r); // r = 61.728000
  $finish; 
end 
endmodule
```

Comment: does real support arrays. Can I declare something like real r[0:10][0:10] ??

Comment: Since the user tagged the question with SystemVerilog, I assume that is what they are using. Yes, there are arrays of any type in SystemVerilog

Comment: @dave_59: it's also tagged with `Verilog`, where are no real arrays.